# Xamarin Forms SQLite.Net PCL is not working on WinPhone 8.1

Tags: c#, xamarin, windows-phone-8.1, xamarin.forms, sqlite.net

I was trying to configure SQLite.NET PCL for WinPhone 8.1 but all the time when I am trying to access data it is crashing.(don't have any errors during the build)

Before the crash during the debug mode it stops and brings me to this:

```
if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
{
if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
};
```

That my code:

```
var sqliteFilename = "XamarinWMS.db3";
    string path = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, sqliteFilename);
    var platform = new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT();
    var conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(platform, path);
    return conn;
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in XamarinWMS.DLL

Comment: Did your code write in `pcl` project?

Comment: The code example is from WinPhone 8.1 project, but the problem was that i was using a plugin which doesn't support windows phone 8.1, had to switch to a different one